# Update color of shape based on cell with calculated value

Tags: excel, vba

Scenario: I have a dashboard with tiles for things such as "Overdue Tasks".  I have a shape called `tileOverdueTasks`.  On top of it I have a wordart with a value of `=Z11`.  Cell Z11 is calculated based on values in a *separate* sheet (`Sheet5 (Tasks)`).  If `Tasks.Z11 = 0` I want `tileOverdueTasks` to be green.  If it's anything else, I want it to be red.

I found the code below but it does not seem to trigger, I'm assuming due to the fact that cell Z11 is not being changed manually and thus neither is the `ActiveWorkbook`.  So, how can I modify this to work given the scenario above?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Z11")) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
            If Target.Value > 0 Then
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("tileOverdueTasks").Fill.BackColor.RGB = vbRed
            Else
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("tileOverdueTasks").Fill.BackColor.RGB = vbGreen
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

UPDATE: I have changed the event to `Worksheet.calculate` as suggested by @Scott Craner.  Now the event fires and it even enters the proper condition, however the color is not changing.

Comment: Look into the Worksheet_calculate event.

Comment: That helped but please see my edit.  I put in some MsgBox's so I know it's entering the proper condition but the shape color doesn't change.

Comment: Figured it out, it needs to be `Fill.ForeColor`.  Please post an answer and I will aCcept.

Comment: Glad I could help.  A formal answer is not needed. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

There were two problems.

1) As pointed out by [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner), I needed to use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event.

2) Due to the style of the shape, `Fill.BackColor` was not working.  I changed it to `Fill.ForeColor` and now it works.

Here is the working code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Sheets("Dashboard").Range("Z11").Value > 0 Then
        Sheets("Dashboard").Shapes("tileOverdueTasks").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(185, 0, 0)
    Else
        Sheets("Dashboard").Shapes("tileOverdueTasks").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 185, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```